# Recovering files from Recycle bin failed and files went permanently missing

Tags: windows

I tried to restore a folder from Recycle bin, but it failed midway saying that a bin subdirectory in the original folder location are being used by some process. After I unlocked the bin directory and did a restore again, only the bin directory is seen, not the rest of the directory contents. I have no idea where it put the rest of the files that it apparantly restored in the first attempt.
Please tell if there is anyway I can recover the lost files, before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 0):

Before I shot myself, I would try Start -> Search ... from the top level; and for a bunch of different files. You might be surprised and delighted.

-- pete

Answer (score 0):

Try what pete said.
If still cannot find the folder, very important to not save any new files or data to the device or computer concerned. At the same time put your device in safe place. Don't let them have the possibility to encouter physical damage. As data overwritten or physical damage will make the deleted data extremely hard to be recovered.Then the most effective way to recover your deleted files is by relying on a [data recovery tool](http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery/index.html).